# pymongo update_one(), upsert=True without using $ operators

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have documents in the form:

```
{"hostname": "myhost1.com", "services": { ... } }
```

What I'd like to do is the following:

```
dataset = requests.get('http://endpoint.com/hardware.json').json()
for hostname, services in dataset[0].items():
    db.titleHardware.update_one({'hostname':hostname},
                                {services.keys()[0]: services.values()[0]}, 
                                True) #upsert
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: update only works with $ operators

Is there a way to accomplish this update of the entire `"services"` chunk, based on the `"hostname"` key (and ultimately, inserting a new document if `hostname` doesn't exist)? I know I can write logic to compare what's in my MongoDB with what I'm trying to update/insert, but I was hopeful that there may be something already in `pymongo` or something that I could use for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use replace_one to replace documents.

```
for hostname, services in dataset[0].items():
    db.titleHardware.replace_one({'hostname':hostname},
                                 {'hostname':hostname,
                                  services.keys()[0]: services.values()[0]}, 
                                 True)
```

Comment: which is faster? replace_one or update_one with $set?

Answer (score 15):

Did you look at the mongodb documentation for [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/)? 
You have to specify an update operator such as `$set`:

```
for hostname, services in dataset[0].items():
    db.titleHardware.update_one({'hostname':hostname},
                                {'$set': {services.keys()[0]: services.values()[0]}}, 
                                upsert=True)
```