# Update_one or insert_many to update records in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I'm new to `MongoDB` and already inserted a table to my collection. Now I have new data (added new rows and updated values) but I don't know  `update_one` or `update_many` which one should be used to update the records in the collection.

The data in my database

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, UpdateOne
import pandas as pd

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6143b5b78d248ba8ed0c3d88"),
    "Sector" : "A",
    "RKK_T" : 0.15,
    "RKK_M" : 0.2,
    "lastModified" : ISODate("2021-09-16T22:23:45.411Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6143b5b78d248ba8ed0c3d89"),
    "Sector" : "B",
    "RKK_T" : 0.22,
    "RKK_M" : 0.3,
    "lastModified" : ISODate("2021-09-16T22:23:45.411Z")
}
```

And this is my new data that I want to push it to the database

```
data = [{
    "_id" : "6143b5b78d248ba8ed0c3d88",
    "Sector" : "A",
    "RKK_T" : 0.15,
    "RKK_M" : 0.25,
    "lastModified" :datetime.utcnow()
},
{
    "_id" : "6143b5b78d248ba8ed0c3d89",
    "Sector" : "B",
    "RKK_T" : 0.22,
    "RKK_M" : 0.3,
    "lastModified" : datetime.utcnow()
},
{
    "_id" : "6143b5b78d248ba8ed0c3d90",
    "Sector" : "C",
    "RKK_T" : 0.25,
    "RKK_M" : 0.32,
    'RKK_K' : 0.4,
    "lastModified" : datetime.utcnow()
}
]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['_id', 'Sector', 'RKK_T', 'RKK_M', 'lastmodified'])
    df

    _id                     Sector  RKK_T   RKK_M   lastmodified
0   6143b5b78d248ba8ed0c3d88    A   0.15    0.25    NaN
1   6143b5b78d248ba8ed0c3d89    B   0.22    0.30    NaN
2   6143b5b78d248ba8ed0c3d90    C   0.25    0.32    NaN
```

So I think I need to filter by each `Sector` and update values of `RKK_T` and `RKK_M` columns.

So based on my research I think one way to update the `collection` with new `data` is

```
  for i in range(len(data)):
   print(i)
   for key, values in data[i].items():

#        print(key, values)

        collection.update_one({'Sector': 'Sector'},
                                {'$set': {key.keys()[i]: values.values()[i]}, "$currentDate": {"lastModified": True}}, 
                                upsert=True)
```

but got this error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

I really need a help for kick start:)
Thanks in advance!

[pymongo update_one(), upsert=True without using $ operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110924/pymongo-update-one-upsert-true-without-using-operators)

[PyMongo & Pandas - Update multiple records in MongoDB collection from dataframe by matching id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159686/pymongo-pandas-update-multiple-records-in-mongodb-collection-from-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How do I update a Mongo document after inserting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372797/how-do-i-update-a-mongo-document-after-inserting-it)

Answer (score 1):

use bulkWrite

create for like this

```
a = []
b = {}
for d in data :
    b = {'updateOne':{
          "filter": {'Sector':d['Sector']},
           "update":{'$set':{
                      "RKK_T":d["RKK_T"],
                       "RKK_M" : d["RKK_M"],
                       'RKK_K' :d["RKK_K"],
                       "lastModified" :d["lastModified"]
                     }}
         }}
    a.append(b)
    db.collection.bulk_write(a)
```

it will be like this

```
db.collection.bulk_Write( [
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter": {Sector:"A"},
         "update":{$set:{"RKK_T" : 0.25,
                         "RKK_M" : 0.32,
                          'RKK_K' : 0.4,
                          "lastModified" : datetime.utcnow()}}           
                      
      },
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter": {Sector:"B"},
         "update":{$set:{"RKK_T" : 0.25,
                         "RKK_M" : 0.32,
                          'RKK_K' : 0.4,
                          "lastModified" : datetime.utcnow()}}           
                      
      },
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter": {Sector:"A"},
         "update":{$set:{"RKK_T" : 0.25,
                         "RKK_M" : 0.32,
                          'RKK_K' : 0.4,
                          "lastModified" : datetime.utcnow()}}           
                      
      }
]
)
```

Comment: I got this error `'dict' object has no attribute '_add_to_bulk'`